# A question for uniform convergent of sequence of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, complete-spaces

Consider the sequence of functions $<f_n(t)>$, defined as
$
f_n(t) = 
\begin{cases}
    e^{-t^2} & \text{if } -n \leq t \leq n \\
    \frac{e^{-n^2}}{[1-n(t-n)]} & \text{if } n \leq t < n + \frac{1}{n} \\
    \frac{e^{-n^2}}{[1+n(t+n)]} & \text{if } -n - \frac{1}{n} < t \leq -n \\
    0 & \text{if } |t| \geq n + \frac{1}{n}
\end{cases}
$

I know it is point-wise convenient to $e^{-t^2}$ over $\mathbb R.$ I cannot check its uniform convergent as $$|f_n(t)-e^{-t^2}|=\begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if } -n \leq t \leq n \\
    |\frac{e^{-n^2}}{[1-n(t-n)]}-e^{-t^2}| & \text{if } n \leq t < n + \frac{1}{n} \\
    |\frac{e^{-n^2}}{[1+n(t+n)]}-e^{-t^2}|& \text{if } -n - \frac{1}{n}< t \leq -n \\
    e^{-t^2}& \text{if } |t| \geq n + \frac{1}{n}
\end{cases}$$
Now stuck. Please help.

Comment: Note that $f_n$ is unbounded to the left of $t:=n+1/n$; it might be a typo but, if not, you can use this, since you already computed the pointwise limit.

Comment: @Jose27 Sir I am unable to do the next calculation. If possible please give a calculation. I checked it there is no typo.

Comment: Uniform convergence amounts to showing that $a_n:=\sup_{t\in \mathbb{R}} |f_n(t)-e^{-t^2}|$ tends to 0 as $n\to \infty$. With the observation in the previous comment above, what can you say about $a_n$ for a fixed $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Jose27 it seems that it tends to infity and hence not uniform convergent?

Comment: That's correct.